# ExtJS - How to reference "self" in a custom function in a custom class?

Tags: javascript, scope, extjs4

How do I reference an instance of a custom class inside a custom function defined within the class?

I've extended a class through ExtJS4's class extension "mechanism", and I've a custom event handler that will be called when something is triggered, and I want to collapse the Panel when something is fired.

However, in the event handler of the Reactor class below, "this" references EventTriggerer (The firer of the event) instead of the instance of the Reactor. How do I reference the instance of the EventReactor inside a custom function?

Thanks!
DashK

```
Ext.define('EventReactor', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    onSomething: function(data) {
        // ERROR
        // this.collapse is undefined. "this" actually references EventTriggerer
        this.collapse();
    }
});

Ext.define('EventTriggerer', {
    extend: 'Ext.util.Observable',
    singleton: true,
    constructor: function() {
        this.addEvents({
        "changedView" : true
    });
},
doSomething: function() {
    // Do some stuff
    this.fireEvent("doneSomething", data);
    }
});

...

// Here's how the listeners are added
var er = Ext.create('EventReactor');
EventTriggerer.addListener("doneSomething", er.onSomething);

// Here's how the event is triggered.
er.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should create a nested scope to store "this" during constructor execution:

```
Ext.define('EventReactor', function() {
    var self;  // This is a variable to store "this"

    return {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

        constructor: function() {
            self = this;  // Here you store "this" in the closure
            self.callParent(arguments);
        },

        onSomething: function(data) {
            // ERROR
            // this.collapse is undefined. "this" actually references EventTriggerer
            // this.collapse();

            // Using "self" instead of "this" => No error
            self.collapse();
        }
    };
});
```

Detailed information (see define method): http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext

Comment: I think in the above the function must be self-executing.  So...

`Ext.define('EventReactor', (function(){..return {}...}()));` 
and not 
`Ext.define('EventReactor', function(){..return {}...});`

Answer (score 0):

The [addListener()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-addListener) method has an additional parameter `scope` that can be set to an object that becomes `this` in the event handler.

```
EventTriggerer.addListener("doneSomething", er.onSomething, er);
```

Comment: Is there a way to reference it without passing it in?

Comment: This is not possible, since the [fireEvent()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Observable.html#Ext-util-Observable-method-fireEvent) uses [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to switch the context to the `scope` object and there is no way to reverse it. When the `EventReactor` would have an [itemId](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-itemId) property, then you could query it with [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.ComponentQuery).