# searching for a nice way to get back reference inside event handlers in ExtJS class style component

Tags: javascript, extjs, javascript-objects, extjs4.1, shopware

I am searching for a nice way to get an attribute back reference on ExtJS class style component inside event handler methods.
Background: I am try to code an own Shopware 5.2 shopping worlds widget. Basically, it is an advanced slider with individual text on each slide image. For doing so, I have already one model and store defined, which holds the "real" data, which will be later stored in the database. So, this is not any data that is worth to save, it is more runtime data that is used for referencing the right item in the grid.

The problem here is the same as the classical desktop app problem: Get a reference on object data inside the same class in an event handler, e. g. click handler to save/modify the shown data. Basically, the event handler (e. g. click handler) are independend to the rest of the class and they are also usually declared as static methods in C-like programming languages.

So, I am searching for a nice way (nice way = no code smell) to do this in JavaScript. Since I am new to ExtJS, I may not know all about it. It is also not easy to find solutions and documentation parts to the outdated 4.1 version, that is used in Shopware. I mean not at sencha, and at Shopware devdocs, neither.

Since this is more an ExtJS problem, than it is addressable to Shopware, I am asking here to gain hopefully a wider developer audience.

Ok, so my options that I have figured out so far are:

1. Very bad: define a global variable, that lives in the window scope
2. Maybe not that bad, but also not the optimal solution: Create an ExtJS namespace for that and store the required variable inside it. This is actually done by me and it works (see my code sample below).

Here is the full code that I have coded so far:

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.Emotion.view.components.Unsplash', {
    extend: 'Shopware.apps.Emotion.view.components.Base',
    alias: 'widget.emotion-components-unsplash',

    declareNsGlobals: function () {
        Ext.ns("Unsplash.componentView");
        Unsplash.componentView.imgPos = -1;
    },

    /**
     * Initialize the component.
     *
     * @public
     * @return void
     */
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        me.declareNsGlobals();

        // me.setDefaultValues();
        me.add(me.createBannerFieldset());
        me.initGridData();
        // me.refreshHiddenValue();
    },

    /**
     * Creates the fieldset which holds the banner administration. The method
     * also creates the banner store and registers the drag and drop plugin
     * for the grid.
     *
     * @public
     * @return [object] Ext.form.FieldSet
     */
    createBannerFieldset: function () {
        var me = this;

        me.slideEditorItem = me.getSlideEditorItem();

        me.mediaSelection = Ext.create('Shopware.form.field.MediaSelection', {
            fieldLabel: me.snippets.select_banner,
            labelWidth: 100,
            albumId: -3,
            listeners: {
                scope: me,
                selectMedia: me.onAddBannerToGrid
            }
        });

        me.bannerStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: [ 'position', 'path', 'link', 'altText', 'title', 'mediaId', 'slideText' ]
        });

        me.ddGridPlugin = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop');

        me.cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2
        });

        me.bannerGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            columns: me.createColumns(),
            autoScroll: true,
            store: me.bannerStore,
            height: 200,
            plugins: [ me.cellEditing ],
            viewConfig: {
                plugins: [ me.ddGridPlugin ],
                listeners: {
                    scope: me,
                    drop: me.onRepositionBanner
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                scope: me,
                edit: function () {
                    me.refreshHiddenValue();
                }
            }
        });

        return me.bannerFieldset = Ext.create('Ext.form.FieldSet', {
            title: me.snippets.banner_administration,
            layout: 'anchor',
            'defaults': { anchor: '100%' },
            items: [ me.slideEditorItem, me.mediaSelection, me.bannerGrid ]
        });
    },

    /**
     * Factory method for the TinyMCE form element creation.
     *
     * @returns {Shopware.form.field.TinyMCE}
     */
    getSlideEditorItem: function () {
        return Ext.create('Shopware.form.field.TinyMCE', {
            name: 'slide_editor',
            id: 'slide_editor',
            translatable: false,
            fieldLabel: 'Slide Text',
            labelWidth: 100
        });
    },

    /**
     * Helper method which creates the column model
     * for the banner administration grid panel.
     *
     * @public
     * @return [array] computed columns
     */
    createColumns: function () {
        var me = this, snippets = me.snippets;

        return [ {
            header: '&#009868;',
            width: 24,
            hideable: false,
            renderer: me.renderSorthandleColumn
        }, {
            dataIndex: 'path',
            header: snippets.path,
            flex: 1
        }, {
            dataIndex: 'link',
            header: snippets.link,
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: true
            }
        }, {
            dataIndex: 'altText',
            header: snippets.altText,
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: true
            }
        }, {
            dataIndex: 'title',
            header: snippets.title,
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: true
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            header: snippets.actions,
            width: 60,
            items: [ {
                iconCls: 'sprite-minus-circle',
                action: 'delete-banner',
                scope: me,
                handler: me.onDeleteBanner
            }, {
                iconCls: 'sprite-pencil',
                action: 'editSlideTextWhatever',
                tooltip: "load slide text in editor and update it",
                scope: me,
                handler: me.onEditSlideText
            } ]
        } ];
    },

    /**
     * Refactor sthe mapping field in the global record
     * which contains all banner in the grid.
     *
     * Adds all banners to the banner administration grid
     * when the user opens the component.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    initGridData: function () {
        var me = this,
            elementStore = me.getSettings('record').get('data'), bannerSlider;

        // TODO: check if this below works?!
        Ext.each(elementStore, function (element) {
            if (element.key === 'banner_slider') {
                bannerSlider = element;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (bannerSlider && bannerSlider.value) {
            Ext.each(bannerSlider.value, function (item) {
                me.bannerStore.add(Ext.create('Shopware.apps.Emotion.model.Unsplash', item));
            });
        }
    },

    /**
     * Event listener method which will be triggered when one (or more)
     * banner are added to the banner slider.
     *
     * Creates new models based on the selected banners and
     * assigns them to the banner store.
     *
     * @public
     * @event selectMedia
     * @param [object] field - Shopware.MediaManager.MediaSelection
     * @param [array] records - array of the selected media
     */
    onAddBannerToGrid: function (field, records) {
        var me = this, store = me.bannerStore;

        Ext.each(records, function (record) {
            var count = store.getCount();
            var model = Ext.create('Shopware.apps.Emotion.model.Unsplash', {
                position: count,
                path: record.get('path'),
                mediaId: record.get('id'),
                link: record.get('link'),
                altText: record.get('altText'),
                title: record.get('title'),
                slideText: record.get('slideText')
            });
            store.add(model);
        });

        // We need a defer due to early firing of the event
        Ext.defer(function () {
            me.mediaSelection.inputEl.dom.value = '';
            me.refreshHiddenValue();
        }, 10);

    },

    /**
     * Event listener method which will be triggered when the user
     * deletes a banner from banner administration grid panel.
     *
     * Removes the banner from the banner store.
     *
     * @event click#actioncolumn
     * @param [object] grid - Ext.grid.Panel
     * @param [integer] rowIndex - Index of the clicked row
     * @param [integer] colIndex - Index of the clicked column
     * @param [object] item - DOM node of the clicked row
     * @param [object] eOpts - additional event parameters
     * @param [object] record - Associated model of the clicked row
     */
    onDeleteBanner: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, eOpts, record) {
        var me = this;
        var store = grid.getStore();
        var globImgPos = Unsplash.componentView.imgPos;
        store.remove(record);
        console.log("Unsplash.componentView.imgPos", Unsplash.componentView.imgPos);
        console.log("record position:", record.get("position"));
        // console.log("eOpts scope imgPos", eOpts.scope);

        if (globImgPos > -1 && record.get("position") === globImgPos) {
            Ext.getCmp("slide_editor").setValue("", false);
        }
        me.refreshHiddenValue();
    },

    /**
     * Event listener method which will be triggered when the user
     * whishes to edit a banner slide text from banner administration grid panel.
     *
     * Removes the banner from the banner store.
     *
     * @event click#actioncolumn
     * @param [object] grid - Ext.grid.Panel
     * @param [integer] rowIndex - Index of the clicked row
     * @param [integer] colIndex - Index of the clicked column
     * @param [object] item - DOM node of the clicked row
     * @param [object] eOpts - additional event parameters
     * @param [object] record - Associated model of the clicked row
     */
    onEditSlideText: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, eOpts, record) {
        var me = this;
        // TODO: defer load and growl message on after done
        var htmlEditor = Ext.getCmp('slide_editor');
        Unsplash.componentView.imgPos = record.get("position");
        htmlEditor.setValue(record.get("slideText") + " behind that " + record.get("position"), false);
    },

    /**
     * Event listener method which will be fired when the user
     * repositions a banner through drag and drop.
     *
     * Sets the new position of the banner in the banner store
     * and saves the data to an hidden field.
     *
     * @public
     * @event drop
     * @return void
     */
    onRepositionBanner: function () {
        var me = this;

        var i = 0;
        globImgPos = Unsplash.componentView.imgPos;
        me.bannerStore.each(function (item) {
            // also update the imgPos to detect item deletion also right after repositioning, if there is one already defined
            if (globImgPos > -1 && globImgPos === item.get("position")) {
                Unsplash.componentView.imgPos = i;
            }

            item.set('position', i);
            i++;
        });
        me.refreshHiddenValue();
    },

    /**
     * Refreshes the mapping field in the model
     * which contains all banners in the grid.
     *
     * @public
     * @return void
     */
    refreshHiddenValue: function () {
        var me = this,
            store = me.bannerStore,
            cache = [];

        store.each(function (item) {
            cache.push(item.data);
        });
        var record = me.getSettings('record');
        record.set('mapping', cache);
    },

    /**
     * Renderer for sorthandle-column
     *
     * @param [string] value
     */
    renderSorthandleColumn: function () {
        return '<div style="cursor: move;">&#009868;</div>';
    }
});
```

A few noticeable-worth points to it:

1. This code was originally made for another widget in the Shopware coding book. I used this as a starting point, because I could only get this widget working. So I removed all unneeded code and replaced it with my own. Since it is still in development, there might be some back references or names from the original widget in there. One is the brand name "Unsplash". As I said, I was not able to change this in order to result in a working widget. Of course, this will be changed before the development cylce ends. So, no real end user would see those brand names in my widget. It is just for now (me and my locally installed develop environment).
2. I also copied a lot of function logic from the Shopware "banner slider" widget, since it does nearly the same as I need to do. So you may find some similarities to the original widget(s).
3. In addition to my point 2 the working code sample is shortened. If you are interested in those small maybe not shown functions, you will find it here: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.2/themes/Backend/ExtJs/backend/emotion/view/components/banner_slider.js

Also the media widget could be found there.

4. The widget that I originally used as my starting base can be found here: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gxmedia.galileo-press.de/supplements/4185/4243_Zusatzmaterialien.zip

Respective authors of this widget (under section 7) are Daniel Nögel (book author), the Shopware AG (assistance for the book) and many others. There is actually no explicit license given for those code samples. Since this is a how to do sth book, I assume that I have rights to use this code in my widgets.

Edit: This is how the ExtJS dialog actually looks like:
[image: advanced slider with pictures and text ExtJS dialog]

Answer (score 1):

All your event handlers are normal methods, not static, and scoped to `me`, which is the component itself.

This makes it really easy: You would extend the component object. So, instead of `Unsplash.componentView.imgPos`, you would use `me.imgPos` or `this.imgPos` (depending on whether you define `var me = this` at the start of the event listener or not).

Comment: I tried that before asking. It did not work. My class attribute has always lost the reference. In the event handlers it was every time the initial value, not the user chosen value from before. This is bad for deleting, because it would delete the wrong grid entry. Also, if I don't pass the `scope` key in my columns, the attribute works, but he says, that `me.refreshHiddenValue()` is undefined?! So, using namespace was the first option I found in that both things work.

Comment: Please put a `console.log(me)` into all listeners and check whether they are pointing to the component. I guess you have a scoping problem to fix.

Comment: Yeah. that was it, but not in the way you described in your answer. As always in JavaScript `this` in an event function references to the event itself, and not as often excepted to the class or object. I can't believe that I had run hundred of times in this issue and I did not also recognized it here...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the reference problem by myself. I have found another question here, from which the author has had the exact problem as I had. This behaviour in ExtJS only applies in event handler functions, because ExtJS simulates a class style programming, but this was one of the exceptions in which it is "nearly" object orientation. JavaScript does not differ between static and not static. So, this totally solved my issue, too: [ExtJS - How to reference "self" in a custom function in a custom class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441502/extjs-how-to-reference-self-in-a-custom-function-in-a-custom-class)

I just declared an object reference to itself like this:

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.Emotion.view.components.Unsplash', {
    extend: 'Shopware.apps.Emotion.view.components.Base',
    alias: 'widget.emotion-components-unsplash',
    // [...]
    objRef: null,
    // [...]
```

And then in initComponent the magic applies:

```
initComponent: function () {
    objRef = this;
    // [...]
},
```

I needed also to change every event handler from `var me = this;` simply to `objRef`. E. g.:

```
onEditSlideText: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, eOpts, record) {
    // TODO: defer load and growl message on after done
    var htmlEditor = Ext.getCmp('slide_editor');
    Unsplash.componentView.imgPos = record.get("position");
    htmlEditor.setValue(record.get("slideText"), false);

    objRef.setEditorButtonNumberVal(Unsplash.componentView.imgPos);
}
```

Everything else than events can stay on the old style using `var me = this;`. This issue only applies to events.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the context in a called function, you can bind the context on the call of the fonction.

For example:

```
  me.add(me.createBannerFieldset.bind(me).call());
```

It will use the context where the execution is.

So if you call fctA you alert "

Edit: Example

```
this.fctA = function() {
  var me = this;
  this.valA = true;
  this.valB = false;
  fctInsideA() {
      //here *this*  is relatate to fctInsideA not fctA
      me.fctC.bind(me).call();
  }
}

this.fctB = function() {
  var me = this;
  this.valA = false;
  this.valB = true;
  fctInsideB() { 
      //here *this*  is relatate to fctInsideB not fctB
      me.fctC.bind(me).call();
  }
}

this.fctC = function() {
  if(this.valA)
    alert("A context");

  if(this.valB)
    alert("B context);  

}
```

if you use `bind`, the context defined in the current function will be pass as the context in the called function.

So if you call fctA, you alert "A context". If you call fctB, you alert "B context".

Is it more clear?

Comment: May you explain it a bit more, please? I am not sure now, what you mean. Therefore, what would happen if I have two dialog instances open? Do I then bind the instances against each other?

Comment: I made an edit to explain. Let me know if it's not clear